# Modify suds request to target SOAP

Tags: python, soap, suds

I am having a problem with python suds trying to create a proper Suds XML Request:

This is my suds Code (after a few trials):

```
from suds import *
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
import logging

url = 'http://ws/webservices/600/ws.asmx?wsdl'
soap_client = Client(url, location='http://ws/webservices/600/ws.asmx')
soap_client.set_options(port='GatewayWebServiceSoap')

person = soap_client.factory.create('checkIfExists') 
person.UserID = 'toni.tester@anywhere.at'
person.SessionID = ''

eventService = soap_client.service.CustomerService(person)

print 'last received:'                                                                                                                                                                                          
print soap_client.last_received()                                                                                                                                                                               
print '-------------------------------------'                                                                                                                                                                                               
print 'last sent:'
print soap_client.last_sent()
```

This is what my suds sends:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://service.example.at/gateway/v6.00" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <ns1:Body>
       <ns0:Service>
          <ns0:Service>
             <ns0:SessionID></ns0:SessionID>
             <ns0:UserID>toni.tester@anywhere.at</ns0:UserID>
          </ns0:Service>
       </ns0:Service>
    </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And this is what the WebService expects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GATEWAY xmlns="urn:service-example-at:gateway:v4-00">
    <Service>
        <checkIfExists>
            <SessionID></SessionID>
            <UserID>test</UserID>
        </checkIfExists>
    </Service>
</GATEWAY>
```

My Questions:

- How can I change SOAP-ENV:Envelope -> GATEWAY
- How can I remove the namespaces ns1, ns0?
- How can I remove the Body

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't care about WSDL and stuff you can easily write request generator yourself since xml request is just a string template. That's what i [did](https://bitbucket.org/dpwiz/exml/src/) for my soapy needs.

Comment: Sorry, but this is no option - our WSDL Service is really huge :-)